# R: Function: generate and save multiple matrices based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, function, matrix, dataframe

I am a new R user and an unexperienced coder and I have a data handling problem. Hopefully someone can help:

I have a data.frame with 3 columns  (firm, year, class) and about 50.000 rows. I want to generate and store for every firm a (class x year) matrix with class counts as the elements in the matrix. Every matrix would be automatically named something like firm.name and stored so that I can use them afterwards for computations. Ideally, I'd be able to change the simple class counts into a function of values in columns 4 and 5 (backward and forward citations)

I am looking at 40 firms, 30 years, and about 1500 classes (so many firm-year-class counts are zero).

I realise I can get most of what I need (for counts) by simply using table(class,year,firm) as these columns have the same length. However, I don't know how to either store or access the matrices this function generates...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your question is how to deal with a table object?

Example:

```
#note the assigment operator
mytable <- with(ChickWeight, table(cut(weight, c(0,100,200,Inf)), Diet, Chick))

#access the data for the first chick
mytable[,,1]

#turn the table object into a data.frame
as.data.frame(mytable)
```

Comment: Cheers Roland for your superfast reply. Though it took me a while to figure out what it all meant (I'm an R novice) it works really well!.

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter before being done...
Is there a way of automatically naming the tables? e.g. mytable[,,1] = Jef ; mytable[,,2] = Dolly ; mytable[,,i] = Something ... so that the chosen names for the tables depend on the value of i 
(in my case i would ideally refer to a separate vector in which all firm names are stored).